# Firebase dynamic link not found in Flutter App

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm reporting a very strange problem.
I have an app developed in Flutter and I have correctly integrated the Firebase library for using the Dynamic Links service.
The problem is when short links are open on a mobile device, it shows a screen with the message "Save my place in the app. A link will be copied to continue to this page", and a button OPEN to continue.
Using your link debugging tool everything seems ok
When I develop directly in debugging mode the problem does not present itself.
When I install the app from TestFlight sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. It seems random.
the problem could be that the app is not yet available on the store ?